# I can't import/use Geolocation from react-native-geolocation-service

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, typeerror, importerror

When I try using this code;

```
`Geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

It returns a typeError that says,
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of null`
I am building on react native CLI and not using typescript. When I say I can't import/use it, I mean I can write out the import statements like this,

```
Import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service"
```

but it doesn't automatically import like other modules.

I have tried using the @react-native-community/Geolocation library, but the library is not linking with my project as it should and the app doesn't build.
I have tried installing the missing devDependencies from the package.json of the react-native-geolocation-service library, but still for some reason, I can't import/use Geolocation as a module from the library.